# Confusion regarding proposals on Area51?

Tags: support, specific-question, area-51, site-proposal

This is what I call puzzling...

I made a proposal on Area51 and now it's gone - without any explanation. When I go to make another proposal, I get the familiar "you've already made a proposal..." message.

Why do I get this message when there isn't a shred of anything indicating I made one today?

...and how can I find out why my proposal was deleted?

Answer (score 2):

Jon Skeet gets plenty of attention. Yeah, I thought it was entertaining, but maybe inappropriate. Given that, obviously, it is a matter of not resetting your daily proposal count when the previous proposal was deleted. Maybe a bug, but could very easily be by-design.

Comment: I still say it's a bug.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a post getting deleted for being inappropriate shouldn't reload your ability 
to make another.

That would essentially allow one to submit more **inappropriate** proposals in a day than one could **good** ones, which seems sub-optimal.

I found your proposal humorous, but it's deletion seems reaonable.  I *do* agree that since it didn't appear to be truly offensive/illegal/etc, it would be better if there were evidence of it's deletion/closure, but I guess that runs a risk of clogging up the site with "dead trees".

Comment: That's what I'm saying - a reason would have been nice. That way, I could avoid making future proposals with the same problem.