# Is there a way to tell when an Area51 question has been deleted?

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, deleted-questions

I think a question of mine was deleted (which I'm fine with - it was certainly off-topic, and probably not in a boundary-defining way).

As a result, it shows up in my questions, but when you click the link, it takes you to the page where it no longer exists, and there doesn't seem to be a trash bin anywhere to confirm what happened, so at first it just seems like the link (or anchor) from "my questions" is broken.

Ideally, the link in "my questions" would indicate that it's been deleted, and clicking it would take you to where it sits in the trash somewhere.  If the goal is to truly purge the content, marking it closed on "my questions" and eliminating the link probably makes sense.

Given everything else in the works, this is probably low-priority, but thought I'd post it for the list.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52462/confusion-regarding-proposals-on-area51

Comment: @Robert, I saw that one too, but wasn't sure if the issue was the same for proposals and questions.

Comment: There isn't any visible tracking of any kind on the deletions, AFAIK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't see that link unless you have enough rep to see the deleted question.  This has been fixed.